# Совмещение js и php в создании переменной

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно следующее:

У меня есть `$title` в него кладётся имя анкеты пользователя и выводится `while`. Всё как обычно и у меня есть код на js где я создаю переменную, однако проблема в том, что мне нужно это делать для каждого отдельно, а когда я создаю одну анкету, то всё что на js создано для неё, работает и на других.

Пришёл к мнению создания уникальной переменной на js, думал про случайный генератор чисел, но это слишком безалаберно. Решил, что нужно давать переменной js частичку имени анкеты. Вот беда в том, что я не понимаю как данную вещь можно решить, ибо как я понял `var` святое для js и:

> var myMap <?php echo get_the_title() ?> ;

Он очень ругает и не пропускает, подскажите пожалуйста как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: нужно просто убрать пробел

Comment: Спасибо,учту при создании новых вопросов!

Comment: Про пробел - это было про проблему в вопросе `var myMap<?php echo get_the_title() ?> ;` - все ок, если данный код будет обработан пхп

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сперва объявить скрипт и после загрузки страницы присвоить переменной значение. Нажмите F12 и в консоле браузера должны увидеть вывод этой переменной `(console.log(temp))`. Если там будет ошибка или я немного не понял вопрос, *напишите об этом и наша тех.поддержка обязательно свяжется с вами и поможет ;D*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // вместо temp и 123 также может быть переменная из php
        var <?php echo 'temp' ?> = <?php echo 123 ?>; 
        console.log(temp);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: И так: var <?php echo $title ?> = <?php echo 123 ?>; 
И так: var <?php echo get_the_title() ?> = <?php echo 123 ?>; 
Исход один: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: @JoJo76 Я проверял у себя и всё работало, нужно чтобы вы уточнили как и где вы вызываете скрипт, точней покажите в каком файле вы пишите эти строки и перед этим проверьте переменную через `var_dump($title)` что там покажет

Comment: Если я делаю это в самом начале страницы,то выходит: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = " скорее всего потому,что переменной ещё не существует.Когда я вызываю после строчки php с получением переменной то ошибка как я писал выше.Работает у меня тоже,когда название var 'title'.

Comment: @JoJo76 нужен код чтобы понять где у вас ошибка, вы я так понимаю перебираете через `while` массив с `title` именно в теле цикла и нужно формировать `<script>...</script>`

Comment: Искренне извиняюсь,ошибка с моей стороны,так как в названии второй анкеты был пробел.Я сначала не обратил внимание и обновлял смотря на вторую анкету.На первой всё сработало,потому,что она была Test,а вот вторая Test 2.Пойду делать замену пробелов в имени если они существуют.Спасибо большое за помощь!Хорошего дня Вам!

Comment: @JoJo76 обращайтесь, и помните, т.к. php и js с которым вы работаете являются интерпретаторами вы должны выводить переменные через var_dump() в php чтобы видеть тип переменной а в js использовать Компоненты разработчика (обычно клавиша F12) чаще её Консоль, удачного дня и вам ;D